# Two Queries with WP_Query append second one to end with Pagination

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

What I am trying to do is create two queries for properties. One will retrieve the regular results based on a normal query. The second query will retrieve properties closely related to the first query. I am able to run both queries and retrieve all results with posts_per_page set to unlimited and no pagination. The problem when adding pagination is that both loops run and display posts on each page.

The page would have 3 from the first loop followed by 3 from the second loop.

I have tried to merge the two queries into one and show them but the same results happen. 3 and 3.

I am thinking that I need to append somehow to be sure that the second loop is getting output after the first. Any thoughts?

Here are my loops(I excluded args because of length)

```
<?php 
$queryOne = new WP_Query($args);
$queryTwo = new WP_Query($args2);
$results = new WP_Query(); 

$results->posts = array_merge($queryOne->posts, $queryTwo->posts);
?>      

<?php foreach($results->posts as $post) : ?>
  <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
  <?php get_template_part( 'property-listing' ); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure if I know what you're trying to do but have you tried the offset =>3 parameter to avoid duplicates? You could also run two loops but make sure to wp_reset_postdata(); Hope I'm following you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as `parse_query` relies on `post_count` you'll have to add the two post_counts. In your example `post_count` is not set. It should work if you populate the post_count. Simply add this at the end:

```
$results->post_count = $queryOne->post_count + $queryTwo->post_count;
```

Your complete example:

```
<?php 
  $queryOne = new WP_Query($args);
  $queryTwo = new WP_Query($args2);
  $results = new WP_Query(); 

  $results->posts = array_merge($queryOne->posts, $queryTwo->posts);
  $results->post_count = $queryOne->post_count + $queryTwo->post_count;

  foreach($results->posts as $post) : 
     setup_postdata( $post );
     get_template_part( 'property-listing' );

  endforeach;
?>
```